# CSSOMParser in gwt client side

Tags: css, parsing, gwt, import, client

What i would like to do is to read an css file from a GET request on the client side, and then i would like to parse it to check all the classes.

The problem is that I need to implement CSSOMParser for that, and here are the imports

import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSRule;

import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSRuleList;

import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleRule;

import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleSheet;

import com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser;

the problem is that none of those classes ale probably javascript compilant, so they don't want to compile if they're on the client side. Is there a way to get it done ?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the classes are non-GWT-compatible? And if not, which parts of them are non-GWT-compatible? And if they aren't GWT-compatible, can you send the CSS text to a server to parse it there, and return it?

Comment: i need to use only the client side. And the classes are non-GWT-compilant on the client side as i said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is in-itself a CSS Parser, and provides ways to access the style sheets. See http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstylesheets for an introduction.

Since you want to write GWT code to parse the classes, here's what I'd recommend -

1. First understand the javascript code needed to iterate over the classes
2. Write a [Javascript Overlay](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html#javascript-objects), so that you can use java to access the CSS classes and properties
3. Use the abstraction created in step 2 to program whatever logic you require